# i can't update or remove or create my cookies in the same run

Tags: php, html

I am working on a project where it requires two language one is Arabic and one is English
so to handle that i added two links in the footer
for these two language and once the user click in one of them it will send the value through $_GET as AR and EN 
and then create a cookie with these value and call a page named
 ar.php/en.php with text translated depend on the choosen language

## ///////////////THE PROBLEM/////////////////

it does not create or update or remove the cookie in the first try 
when i set the cookie there is a cookie handling after that but it dose
not see the cookie 
i have to let run finish  and open the page and then i retry to execute the code again and the cookie will be there
I tried the same project on netbeans and visual studio but same result i thought it might be a problem with the compiler .

```
 <?php

if(isset($_GET['lang']))
{
    /* one cookie with the same name but the value will change depend on user choice if he changed the language
      and by the value i will call the ar.php or en.php with the array with all the text content of the page  */
    $langu=$_GET['lang'];
    switch($langu)
    {
        case "en":
       setcookie("page_lang", "en", time() +3600,"/"); // set a cookie for english language
        break;
        case "ar":
            setcookie("page_lang", "ar", time()+3600,"/"); // set a cookie for arabic language
            break;
        default:
            setcookie("page_lang", "ar", time() -100,"/");
            break;
    }

}
//$langu="";
include("css/header.html");

    if(isset($_COOKIE['page_lang']))
    {// choosen language
        $cookie_language =$_COOKIE['page_lang'];

        include("lang/{$cookie_language}.php");
    }else
    { //default language
        include("lang/ar.php");
    }


?>
```

Comment: Hi Saleh. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies (and the `$_COOKIE` array) are browser based. So if you do a `setcookie`, it wont be after that requests completes, and the browser sends you more requests that you'll be able to read it.

Just check for the or the GET parameter, so it becomes something like:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['page_lang']) || isset($_GET['lang') )
```

Or check for the variable you are setting earlier when reading `$_GET`.

```
$langu = null;
if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
   $langu = $_GET['lang'];
   switch($_GET['lang'])) {
    case "en":
        // set a cookie for english language
        setcookie("page_lang", "en", time() +3600,"/");

        break;
    case "ar":
        // set a cookie for arabic language
        setcookie("page_lang", "ar", time()+3600,"/"); 
        break;
    default:
        setcookie("page_lang", "ar", time() -100,"/");
        $langu = 'ar';
        break;
  }
}
elseif (isset($_COOKIE['page_lang'])) {
   $langu = $_COOKIE['page_lang'];
}

if (!is_null($langu) {
  include("lang/{$langu}.php");
}
else {
  include("lang/ar.php");
}
```

This way GET has precedence over the cookie (so you can CHANGE languages), and you choose language and set the cookie on the same step.

So: if the users clicked on a language button to change the language, we set the new cookie and display THAT language. If an invalid language was chosen in the parameter, go back to the default language.

If no parameter is present, and a cookie was set previously, show the language selected on the cookie. And if neither parameter nor cookier are set, just show the default language.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? You do understand my code is not complete, right?

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me but i understood the problem <br/> and i want to add one thing and its that the get is only usable when the user choose the language after that it will be all on the cookie if it en then the user will browser the website with english language because the cookie value will stay en so most of the time the $_GET['lang'] will be empty

Comment: Now you have the complete working code. I understood your problem. This fixes it. When the user selects the language the GET parameter will be used, and if the user selected the language previously the cookie option will be.

Comment: i do understand that it need some handling and i added some details into my comment

Comment: This does exactly what you set to accomplish. Give it a try.

Comment: i will try it out

Comment: <h1>This is magic</h1><br/>thanks alot my mistake was the check on the cookie value i should check if there is a new value in get then i should not care about the cookie any way thanks alot